# Setting up CI/CD pipeline for Nextjs13

Tags: next.js

I am looking for example / tutorial how to set-up pipeline (gitlab runner) for Next.js 13 application.

It's a struggle because all resources and documentation are not helpful, I found older examples on the web but I can't make it work with latest version of Next.js.